# Top layer and Top solder layer Altium

Tags: altium

I want to use a microUSB connector on a board I'm designing.
The dimensions of the connector that I'm using is in [this Datasheet](http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/473460001_sd.pdf).

To make a lib I'm using Altium, after setting the dimensions here's how the part looks.

[image]

The problem is that I've checked that my dimensions do match the datasheet, however only on the **Top** layer (red).
When I check the **Top Solder** layer the pads are connected to each other.

[image]

How will this board look if I get it manufactured?
Is the **Top** layer (red) the footprint, or is the **Top Solder** layer (purple) the footprint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Top Solder is the Soldermask (you need to interpret it as a negative layer, violet means no soldermask, empty means soldermask), not your actual pad (that's the Top Layer, positive Layer, red = copper, empty = no copper).

Yet, you could get problems with solder quality if you do not have solder mask between your pads as the solder might easier make shorts between to pins. Maybe you could make your pads a bit smaller to increase the distance which would in turn add soldermask between them.

Comment: Just to make sure, that I've understood your answer, So that  if the violet pads  are connect, it doesn't mean that the pads are electrically connect !

Comment: @Engine That's correct. The Soldermask is essentially the (usually) green lacquer that goes on your PCB. The purple is essentially saying "Please don't put green lacquer here" as it would cover the solderable pads.